# Mult inverse in $\Bbb Z_{26}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I tried doing a problem for finding $7$ inverse in $\mathbb Z_{26}$

I just want to know if my answer of $15$ is correct.

I applied Euclid`s extended theorem and then did back substitution.

My check is $7*15=105=1+26*4=1 \pmod {26}$

Is this reasoning valid?

Comment: Please add math format

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You mean the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, not "Euclid's extended theorem".

Comment: You don't need to do "back substitution" (unless you want to check if your answer is correct). It's enough to apply the Extended Euclidean Algorithm correctly. Your answer $15$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're solving $7x\equiv 1\pmod{26}$, i.e. $7x\equiv 1\pmod{2,13}$.

$7x\equiv 1\pmod{2}\iff x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$

$7x\equiv 1\equiv 14\pmod{13}\stackrel{:7}\iff x\equiv 2\pmod{13}$

By Chinese Remainder Theorem you'll find $x\equiv 15\pmod{26}$.

Another (more general) way of solving $7x\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ is using the Extended Euclidean algorithm to find $s,t\in\mathbb Z$ such that $7s+13t=1$. Then $7s\equiv 1\pmod{13}$, so $x\equiv s\pmod{13}$.

Subtract consecutive equations:

$$13=(1)(13)+(0)(7)\\7=(0)(13)+(1)(7)\\6=(1)(13)+(-1)(7)\\1=(-1)(13)+(2)(7)$$

Therefore $(2)(7)\equiv 1\pmod{13}$, so $x\equiv 2\pmod{13}$.

Yet another way of solving $7x\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ is noticing that by Euler's Theorem $x\equiv 7^{\phi(13)-1}\equiv 7^{11}\pmod{13}$.

$$7^{11}\equiv 49^5\cdot 7\equiv (-3)^5\cdot 7\equiv 81\cdot (-21)\equiv 3\cdot 5\equiv 2\pmod{13}$$